# AttributeError at 'list' object has no attribute 'objects'

Tags: python, django

I am learning `Django` and got the following error.

> AttributeError at  'list' object has no attribute 'objects'

This is my code:

```
Models.py 

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class post(models.Model):`

    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    author =  models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete = models.CASCADE)  

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

Views.py :

from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import post

#lets add some dummy data
post = [
    {
        'author':'raj kumar',
        'title' :'blog title 1',
        'date_posted':'27 August 2020 ',
        "content" :"fist post content"

    },
    {
        'author': "kathir",
        'title': 'blog title 2',
        'date_posted':"28 August 2020 ",
        "content" :"second post content"   
    }
]

def home(request):
    context = {
        "posts": post.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request,'blog/home.html',context)

def blog(request):
    return render(request,'blog/blog.html')
```

- I created some objects with a database using `Django` `ORM`. I inserted some data using the `post` class.

```
>>post.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<post:blog1>,<post:blog2>,<post:blog3>]
```

Comment: Is that the entire error output? What do/don't you understand from that error message?

Comment: Improved formatting and grammar.